# Assertion Errors while importing Keras modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, anaconda

I installed Keras using Pip and when I am trying to import modules from Keras, it gives me an assertion error on utils and init modules.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-eda57b582878> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>()
  1 from __future__ import absolute_import
  2 
----> 3 from . import utils
  4 from . import activations
  5 from . import applications

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
  4 from . import data_utils
  5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
  7 
  8 # Globally-importable utils.

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>()
  7 from six.moves import range
  8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
 10 
 11 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>()
 34     assert isinstance(_epsilon, float)
 35     _backend = _config.get('backend', _BACKEND)
 ---> 36     assert _backend in {'theano', 'tensorflow', 'cntk'}
 37     _image_data_format = _config.get('image_data_format',
 38                                      image_data_format())

 AssertionError:
```

I found a similar question in SOF and checked

```
 python -c "from keras import backend"
```

in cmd prompt and it gives me the following error.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   from . import utils
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   from . import conv_utils
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
  from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
assert _backend in {'theano', 'tensorflow', 'cntk'}

AssertionError
```

Keras.json:

```
{
"image_dim_ordering": "tf",
"backend": "mxnet",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"floatx": "float32"
}
```

What should I be changing in these modules to avoid this error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a file on your system at `~/.keras/keras.json`? If yes, can you print out any `backend` option in it?

Comment: Hi @ely, Have update the json file in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update with the contents of your `keras.json` file, it appears you have set the backend to `"mxnet"`, but [this is not a permitted backend of Keras](https://keras.io/#installation).

Change this value to one of `"tensorflow"`, `"theano"`, or `"cntk"` and be sure you have that corresponding package also installed. Save the file and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @ely. I changed the backend to "tensorflow" in the keras.json file and the error is resolved now. I am able to import the modules successfully. thanks again :)